# Golang parse map encoded in jwt

Tags: go

in my golang project I need to parse and decode some data, encoded in JWT token. For this purpose I am using `github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/jwt`. The data is as follows:

```
"ver": "some ver", 
"pds": {
  "r": [
    {
      "comp": "some_string",
      "dur": 20,
      "u": "DAY",
      "res": "some other string"
    }
  ]
}
```

So I can decode primitive strings (`ver`), which is pretty simple, but I cannot decode objects and arrays and keep getting an error. I tried the following:

```
tokenRaw := "my_jwt_token_here"
reader := strings.NewReader(tokenRaw)
token, err := jwt.Parse(reader)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

type pdsrStruct struct {
    Comp     string `json:"comp"`
    Duration int    `json:"dur"`
    Unit     string `json:"u"`
    Res      string `json:"res"`
}
type R []pdsrStruct
type Pds map[string]R

var ok bool
var pds Pds
if ret, found := token.Get("pds"); found {
    if pds, ok = ret.(Pds); !ok {
        return nil, er.Errorf("failed to parse")
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: People generally use the `encoding/json` package for this. You might have to wrap the text in some `"{"` ... `"}"` pairs to get it to parse.

Answer (score 0):

```golang
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
)

var text = []byte(`
{
   "pds": {
      "r": [
         {
            "dur": 20,
            "u": "DAY"
         }
      ]
   }
}
`)

func main() {
   var s struct {
      Pds struct {
         R []struct {
            Dur int
            U string
         }
      }
   }
   json.Unmarshal(text, &s)
   fmt.Printf("%+v\n", s) // {Pds:{R:[{Dur:20 U:DAY}]}}
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).